# How does Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll work in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I am using Unity to create 2D sidescroller game. In my game I have a person that does a melee attack. In order to implement this I am using 
Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll().

- The first parameter is the position of the box.
- The second parameter is the size.
- The third parameter is the angle.
- The fourth parameter is the layerMask.

I am having trouble understanding the second and third parameters. What does angle mean? Also I am having trouble understanding the size is relative to which units?

Relevant Code:

My Attack Function:

```
    void Attack() {
    Vector2 tempx = new Vector2 (AttackTransform.position.x, AttackTransform.position.y);
    Vector2 tempy = new Vector2 (AttackTransform.position.x + swordSwingRange.x, AttackTransform.position.y + swordSwingRange.y);

    Collider2D[] enemies = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll (tempx,tempy,0,AttackLayerMask);
    Debug.DrawLine (AttackTransform.position, new Vector3(tempy.x,tempy.y, AttackTransform.position.z));
    print (enemies.Length);

}
```

Explanation: The AttackTransform is the starting position where I would like to instantiate my attack. tempx and tempy are the starting and ending positions respectively. 'enemies' is used to find the the number of colliding objects which i will later iterate to decrease health or something.

In my Debug.DrawLine function it draws a line from the start position to the endposition. Hence shouldn't it draw a line that represents the box that will be formed for Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll() ? However as I have experimented with that it does not so. So what scale of units do the aforementioned methods use?

Another side-question:
Is this the best way to detect collision in front of me? Or is there a better way? Any links would be appreciated I can study up further!

Thank you so much for taking the patience to read my question! And I greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `size` is measured in world units, measured from one side of the box to the other, with `point` specifying the center.

If I wanted a box running between (1, 2) at its bottom left to (3, 5) at its top-right, that would be `point = (2, 3.5)` (the center) and `size = (2, 3)` (total width & height in world units)

The `angle` is a z rotation applied to the box.

So if you create a new default cube primitive at the top level of your hierarchy, and set its scale equal to the size you want, and the z rotation to the angle, the result will match the area checked by OverlapBox.

We can also make a preview function to draw it:

```
void DebugDrawBox( Vector2 point, Vector2 size, float angle, Color color, float duration) {

    var orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);

    // Basis vectors, half the size in each direction from the center.
    Vector2 right = orientation * Vector2.right * size.x/2f;
    Vector2 up = orientation * Vector2.up * size.y/2f;

    // Four box corners.
    var topLeft = point + up - right;
    var topRight = point + up + right;
    var bottomRight = point - up + right;
    var bottomLeft = point - up - right;

    // Now we've reduced the problem to drawing lines.
    Debug.DrawLine(topLeft, topRight, color, duration);
    Debug.DrawLine(topRight, bottomRight, color, duration);
    Debug.DrawLine(bottomRight, bottomLeft, color, duration);
    Debug.DrawLine(bottomLeft, topLeft, color, duration);
}
```

In your case, it looks like you want your first argument to be just `AttackTransform.position` if that's the center of your attack range (`Vector3`s can implicitly truncate to xy `Vector2`s, so you don't need to split out its components manually), and your second argument can be `swordSwingRange` on its own (assuming it's an end-to-end distance and not a half-extent)