# How to properly visualize Physics2D.CircleCast function in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a `Physics2D.CircleCast()` function in order to set `true` or `false` if the character is on the ground.

Based on this function, I want to draw a circle, mostly for debugging. I think this method could be quite useful to understand distances between different objects. such as between the character and the platform. The following image shows the variable set to `true` when the character is on the ground.

[image]

In order to draw the circle, my approach was to create an empty object with a *Line Renderer* component. Then, I created the following script (removing the section in which variables were declared):

```
public class DrawCircleCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Call Game Object
    public GameObject player;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        sizeValue = (2.0f * Mathf.PI) / 0.01f;
        size = (int)sizeValue;
        size++;

        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
        lr.material.color = Color.cyan;
        lr.startWidth = 0.03f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.03f;
        lr.positionCount = size;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        DrawCircle();
    }

    void DrawCircle()
    {
        playerPosition = player.transform.position;
        transform.position = playerPosition;
        radius = player.GetComponent<Player>().shapeRadius; // which is 1f

        theta = 0f;
        thetaScale = 0.01f;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            theta += (2.0f * Mathf.PI * thetaScale);
            x = radius * Mathf.Cos(theta);
            y = radius * Mathf.Sin(theta);
            
            x += gameObject.transform.position.x;
            y += gameObject.transform.position.y;

            pos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            lr.SetPosition(i, pos);
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code creates a circle around the character, as follows:

[image]

So, my next approach consisted on change the circle's position from the character to around the `CircleCast` measure, in order to have a better position. So I added new variables to the function and changed the circle's position:

```
void DrawCircle()
{
    playerPosition = player.transform.position;
    platformPosition = platform.transform.position;

    X = playerPosition.x;
    Y = (playerPosition.y + (platformPosition.y)) / 2;
    
    transform.position = new Vector3(X, Y, 0);
    radius = player.GetComponent<Player>().shapeRadius;

    theta = 0f;
    thetaScale = 0.01f;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        theta += (2.0f * Mathf.PI * thetaScale);
        x = radius * Mathf.Cos(theta);
        y = radius * Mathf.Sin(theta);
        
        x += gameObject.transform.position.x;
        y += gameObject.transform.position.y;

        pos = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        lr.SetPosition(i, pos);
    }
}
```

The result changed as follows:

[image]

Although the circle's position is now located around the `CircleCast` measure, I am missing the distance value that I also added to the `Physics2D.CircleCast()` function.

So my question is how can I improve the circle's position to have a better sense of how `CircleCast` is measuring the distance between two objects (i.e. character and platform). I couldn't relate the distance, which is a parameter of the `Physics2D.CircleCast()` function, to the values I used to draw the circle. How the distance affects `CircleCast()` and how can I use this value to improve the circle's position.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: [I usually use the Debug.DrawLine functions to visualize casts](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/156547/39518). Also, remember that a CircleCast is not a single circle (unless you meant to use OverlapCircle instead?) — it's a circle *travelling* along a line segment. So it has a circle at the start of the line, a circle at the end of the line, and a circle where it first makes contact with an object during that sweep, some distance along that line. The overall envelope of the cast is more like a capsule/oval/pill shape, with rounded ends and a straight section in the middle.

Comment: Thank you, @DMGregory. The explanation was quite useful. Will try the `Debug.DrawLine` method.